# Unsafe Median filter using C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, median

I m doing a project based on image processing and i needed to do median filtering for that.
I did it with unsafe way it took a long time to process (800*600 resolution)

is there a fast open source median filtering algorithm which is implemented in C#?

thanks..

Comment: You might want to use another algorithm implementation [like histogram medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter#Algorithm_implementation_issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ,[AforgeNET](http://www.aforgenet.com/projects/iplab/) where they mention the median filter. They do have a collection of fast algorithms and since you are doing C#, it would be just a few clicks and you should be able to use this library which is vastly popular among image processing developers.

You can also check [EMGUCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) Which is a C# wrapper for OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

Try this [[link]](http://www.gutgames.com/post/Noise-Reduction-of-an-Image-in-C-using-Median-Filters.aspx) implementation - it's fully safe, but quite fast.

**Update**:

The author of this article ([JaCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102298/jacraig)) recommends to use the latest version of his library [[link]](http://cul.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72059#707831) (More details in the comments).

By the way, he wrote quite interesting utility library and the filter part of it: [Craig's Utility Library](http://cul.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Actually, I'd say my code from that post there is rather slow (although for a 800x600 image, it wouldn't be too bad). I'd use either Aforge or the updated version from my utility library: http://cul.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72059#707831